# Set C/C++ compiler for Python extensions

Tags: c++, python, linux

I would like to setup a default C and C++ compiler when building Python extensions under Linux.  I noticed the `--compiler` option to `python setup.py` build, but I am wondering if there is a way of setting this as an environmental variable so that I can specify them just once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible to use an environment variable, but you can create a setup.cfg file. See [Writing the Setup Configuration File](http://docs.python.org/distutils/configfile.html). The following setup.cfg file will try to use the Intel C Compiler:

```
[build_ext] 
compiler=icc
```